# How to enable my WiFi in DELL vostro 1500?

Tags: wireless

My WiFi is off but the connection with cable is okay. How to resolve this problem?

I am using 12.04 with Windows 7.

Comment: If there is a switch in BIOS that controls the Bluetooth hardware make sure that it is turned on.  Next check that all recommended third party drivers are installed (additional drivers in applications) then see if the bluetooth device is available to connect.  If it's still not working it would be helpful to know what the bluetooth device is. Copy and past the output of 'sudo lsusb' into your question if it lists the bluetooth device

Comment: I assume both Ubuntu and windows are not working?

Answer (score 2):

Dell Vostro 1500 has a button on the left side at the rear that is called a 'hardware switch'. Image:

[image]

If this is turned off wifi does not work. If this is active and it still does not work check your BIOS since you might be able to turn it off there too.

Oh and there is no FN combo to activate wifi on a Vostro.